# Having trouble referencing xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to xml and during one of my exercises I was trying to reference my xml schema to my xml file but I keep getting errors from both the xml file and the schema. Here is what my xml file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Individual SYSTEM "geneology.dtd">

<Individual xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com Individual.xsd">

    <IndividualRec Id="G101">
        <FirstName>Adam</FirstName>
        <Surname>Jones</Surname>
        <Age>97</Age>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <PersInfo>
            <Date>15 April 1916</Date>
            <Place>Birmingham</Place>
        </PersInfo>
    </IndividualRec>
<Individual>
```

and here is the xsd code I created to be referred to:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/Individual"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="Individual">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="IndividualRec"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="IndividualRec">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="FirstName"/>
        <xs:element ref="Surname"/>
        <xs:element ref="Age"/>
        <xs:element ref="Gender"/>
        <xs:element ref="PersInfo"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="PersInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Date"/>
        <xs:element ref="Place"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Place" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Please let me know where you may think the error may be.

thanks

Comment: do some research and try to do your homework by your own!

Comment: or post the error messages you are seeing - and the code, or  describe the process, that produces the error.

Comment: Neshpro, isn't the whole point of SO a tool for those in the know to assist those who do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's a mismatch between the namespaces. Your XML's `Individual` is in `http://www.w3schools.com` whereas your XSD targets `http://www.w3schools.com/Individual`

All three references must be in sync: the XSD's targetNamespace, your XML namespace, and the xsi:schemaLocation.

There might be other issues, related to the DTD you're posting; I don't see anything related to stuff that would require content from the DTD, so I would suggest to make sure it works without it.

Otherwise, welcome to SO; to avoid chagrin, you could always go back and edit your post with any other additional information you might consider relevant.

Update:

When you're using a targetNamespace, it is also good to define an alias for it, or make it the default namespace. This is to avoid errors that say "cannot find the definition of Date, Place, etc."; when you ref="Date", as an e.g., the XSD spec expects there a QName (qualified name). Without a default namespace, it would mean {}Date, whereas you XSD defines a {http://www.w3schools.com/Individual}Date.

This is a valid XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/Individual" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/Individual"  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Individual">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="IndividualRec"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="IndividualRec">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="FirstName"/>
                <xs:element ref="Surname"/>
                <xs:element ref="Age"/>
                <xs:element ref="Gender"/>
                <xs:element ref="PersInfo"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="PersInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Date"/>
                <xs:element ref="Place"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Place" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This would be your valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Individual xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/Individual" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com/Individual Individual.xsd">
    <IndividualRec Id="G101">
        <FirstName>Adam</FirstName>
        <Surname>Jones</Surname>
        <Age>97</Age>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <PersInfo>
            <Date>15 April 1916</Date>
            <Place>Birmingham</Place>
        </PersInfo>
    </IndividualRec>
</Individual>
```

I've fixed the namespaces; I assume the `Invididual.xsd` is in the same folder with your XSD file.

I've also removed the DTD - you don't have to, if you really need it. I would stay away from it... for e.g., DTD processing is prohibited by default on certain platforms, so you would have to make additional tweaks to make it work.

The above should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Petru, after some reading and tweaking I was able to resolve a few errors but still have the error: "cannot the declaration of element 'Individual'" this has stumped me as I am now pretty sure I have had this covered. Also should I not use my DTD reference when referencing my xml doc to a schema?

Comment: the schema is now as follows:

Comment: Thanks @Petru, I assumed that was possibly where I went wrong. A lot of the books and sites just mention the purpose of namespaces but without being explicit on their proper use outside the examples they have shown them in. This makes a whole lot more sense. :)
Thanks,
Stan